# php bind_param number of variables doesn't match number of parameters

Tags: php, html, oop, mysqli

(`mysqli_stmt::bind_param():` Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement)

---

I made a users class to handle registration login and profile updates and it all works. However I to receive the above error when a user updates their profile. Lets go step by step.

First I have the form

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstName']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text"  name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lastName']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text"  name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="profileImage">Profile Image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="bio">Bio:</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="bio" id="bio"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
         <input type="submit" name="update" value="Submit Updates" class="btn black pull-left">
    </div>
</form>
```

then I have the upload class that handles the file upload portion of things. This works fine and is used in my users class.

```
class Upload
{   
    public function uploadImages()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
            if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
                $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $fileName = mt_rand(100000, 999999) . $fileName;
                $fileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9.]#i', '', $fileName);
                $fileTmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
                $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
                $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tif', 'tiff', 'gif', '');
                $tmp = explode('.', $fileName);
                $fileExtension = strtolower(end($tmp));

                // if (!$fileTmp) {
                //     die('No File Selected, Please try again - <a href="user-profile-edit.php">Try Again?</a>');
                // }
                if ($fileSize > 2097152) {
                    die('Error, File too big - <a href="user-profile-edit.php">Try Again?</a>');
                }
                if (in_array($fileExtension,$extensions) === false and $fileError === 4) {
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, CURRENTROOT . '../img/upload/profiles/'.$fileName);
                    $GLOBALS['fileName'] = $fileName;
                } elseif (in_array($fileExtension,$extensions) === false) {
                    die('Acceptable file types are jpg, png, tif, and gif - <a href="user-profile-edit.php">Try Again?</a>');
                } else {
                     move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, CURRENTROOT . '../img/upload/profiles/'.$fileName);
                     $GLOBALS['fileName'] = $fileName;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the users class that handles registration, log in and profile updating. This also works sort of. It does everything its intended to do however it does return the above arrow. I'm going to leave out the rest of the class and just show the relevant method.

```
public function userProfileEdit()
{
    $upload = new Upload();
    $upload->uploadImages();

    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $result = $this->con->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID="'.$userID.'"');
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    $_SESSION['firstName'] = $row['firstName'];
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = $row['lastName'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['profileImage'] = $row['profileImage'];
    $_SESSION['bio'] = $row['bio'];

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
            trim($updateFirstName = $_POST['firstName']);
            trim($updateLastName = $_POST['lastName']);
            trim($updateUsername = $_POST['username']);
            trim($updateEmail = $_POST['email']);
            trim($updateProfileImage = $GLOBALS['fileName']);
            trim($updateBio = $_POST['bio']);

            $insert = $this->con->db->prepare('UPDATE users SET 
                firstName="'.$updateFirstName.'", 
                lastName="'.$updateLastName.'", 
                username="'.$updateUsername.'", 
                email="'.$updateEmail.'", 
                profileImage="'.$updateProfileImage.'", 
                bio="'.$updateBio.'" 
                WHERE userID = '.$userID);

            $insert->bind_param('sssssss', $updateFirstName, $updateLastName, $updateUsername, $updateEmail, $updateProfileImage, $updateBio, $userID);
            if ($insert->execute()) {
                $GLOBALS['profileUpdated'] = '<p>Your profile has been updated. <a href="user-profile-edit.php"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh </a>to see changes.</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the scripts work and the file is uploaded and the info is sent to the database. As far as I can see the number of prepared vars is the same as in the `bind_param`. I have tried included and excluding the `$userID` from the prepare and bind. Why am I getting the error? I am especially confused because even though I get the error everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you bind 7 params to the query, but don't use any of them. Instead you insert the variables directly into the query, which leads to the data being (insecurely) inserted into the database.

```
$insert = $this->con->db->prepare('UPDATE users SET 
            firstName="'.$updateFirstName.'", 
            lastName="'.$updateLastName.'", 
            username="'.$updateUsername.'", 
            email="'.$updateEmail.'", 
            profileImage="'.$updateProfileImage.'", 
            bio="'.$updateBio.'" 
            WHERE userID = '.$userID);
```

should be

```
$insert = $this->con->db->prepare('UPDATE users SET 
            firstName= ?, 
            lastName= ?, 
            username= ?, 
            email= ?, 
            profileImage= ?, 
            bio= ? 
            WHERE userID = ?');
```

read more: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php